# if (str) in (list) error with pickle load

Tags: python, list, input, try-catch, pickle

I'm very new and I'm sure the question has been answered a thousand time.
This is just the part of the code posing problem.

```
import pickle
userList = ["user1"]

try:
    with open("userList.pkl", "rb") as liste:
        userList = pickle.load(liste)

except:
    with open("userList.pkl", "wb") as liste:
        pickle.dump(userList, liste)

utilisateur = input("Utilisateur: ")
if utilisateur in userList:
    print("in list")

else:
    print("not in list")
    #add in list
```

and it returns `not in list` when I enter `user1`...

Comment: May we see the content of the serialized `userList` ?

Comment: You are overwriting `userList` when loading from file, are you sure that file has user1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are overwriting userList in this line :

```
userList = pickle.load(liste)
```

check if the file that you are loading from has user1 in it.

Comment: the problem was not where i was searching, thanks ! The first time i ran the program it created the pkl file as intended but it didn't contain what i wanted then when i re-run the program it loaded it and overwrote the list !